# Xcode 9.3 XCTest "No element found at point while computing gesture coordinates" error

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode9.3

In our application, we have a hidden test screen in debug builds which allows us to manipulate the state of the application. For several UI tests (including a [snapshot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/snapshot/) script), we need to access this test screen. This is done by triple tapping with two fingers anywhere on the screen.

```swift
extension XXXTestCase {
    /// Performs a hidden gesture which presents the testing screen.
    func navigateToTestingScreen(file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        app.navigationBars
            .element
            .tap(withNumberOfTaps: 3, numberOfTouches: 2)
        testingScreen.assertExists(file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

This worked fine in Xcode 9.2 (and 11.2 simulator), but Xcode 9.3 (11.3 simulator) gives the following runtime error on the `.tap` method:

`No element found at point {5, 42} while computing gesture coordinates, internal error possibly due to orientation or remote view hosting.`

I checked it wasn't anything with the XCUIElement itself by changing the tap to just `.tap()`, which does not produce any runtime errors. It seems XCTest on Xcode 9.3 has trouble with the multi-touch. How would I fix this?

<sub>Of course, the monkey approach would be to alter the gesture to access the testing screen, but I'm not giving up that easy :)</sub>

### Additional experiments

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
| Xcode | Simulator | Result |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|  9.2  |   11.2    |    v   | <-- not an option when migrated to Swift 4.1
|  9.3  |   11.3    |    X   |
|  9.3  |   11.2    |    X   | *
|  9.3  |   11.1    |    X   | *
|  9.3  |   11.0.1  |    X   | *
|  9.3  |   10.3.1  |    v   | <-- not an option, iOS 10 status bar is styled noticeably different
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

* This combination crashes somewhere else, namely:

```
app.tabBars["main-tab-bar"].buttons["some-identifier"].tap()
```

with the most useful phrase `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. The element exists (and can be manipulated manually by clicking in the Simulator), but sending `tap()` to it raises the exception.